# Is CryEngine documentation compatible with Amazon Lumberyard?

Tags: cryengine, documentation, lumberyard-engine

We are considering using it instead of UE4, and we're curious if the Cryengine docs could be used to help with developing in Lumberyard. I imagine they'd have diverged a bit by this point since Amazon has reportedly added "over 2000 improvements", but figured it'd be worth a shot at investigating.

Never really looked into Lumberyard until now, but I've heard that it has a huge lack of good documentation so I figured it could at least provide a much easier starting point if we could reference both.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the documentation that you find on the internet can be used, but also a lot of parts of Cryengine became deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore.

One of the thing that you should get used to is the Entity System in Lumberyard, which I think is quite well done, and for this feature you can use Amazon Lumberyard's documentation which is quite well written, but is still lacking on a lot of aspects of the Engine.

This is the link of the documentation I'm talking about:
https://aws.amazon.com/it/documentation/lumberyard/

Anyway I'd say that probably one of the biggest problem is the quantity of documentation that Amazon has created so far, it's surely not lacking in quality but is on quantity, but it looks like they are working a lot on this aspect as well.